# The component for route must be a React component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

**The component for route 'Feed' must be a React component.**

I've checked most of the other similar questions here but the majority of them are due to basic syntax (which maybe I have too but am blind to!). I've removed chunks of code that aren't relevant to this issue (navigationOptions and other screens) and can still reproduce the error with just the below:

**./navigators/AppNavigator.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { FeedScreen } from '../screens/FeedScreen';

const FeedStack = createStackNavigator({
  Feed: FeedScreen,
});

const DashboardTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    FeedStack
  }
);

const DashboardStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    DashboardTabNavigator: DashboardTabNavigator
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(DashboardStackNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

**./screens/DashboardScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import AppContainer from '../navigators/AppNavigator';

class DashboardScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}

export default DashboardScreen;
```

**./screens/FeedScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default class FeedScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <View>
    </View>);
  }
}
```

Any idea what I've done wrong here?

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: @illya would you share your `FeedScreen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a default export for FeedScreen ... not a named export:

Try this:

```
 import  FeedScreen  from '../screens/FeedScreen';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import  { FeedScreen }  from  '../screens/FeedScreen'
```

You cannot importe like this if you re exporting by default.
Remove your default export or do replace your importe like this :

```
import  FeedScreen  from  '../screens/FeedScreen'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `export default` statement, that means you can´t import like that, you should provide a variable to store the component.

```
import Component from 'defaultexport'
```